# Are undead immune to nonlethal damage?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, damage-types

Quite a few undead are immune to the *unconscious* condition:

> (Plague Zombie)
> **Immunities** death effects, disease, mental, paralyzed, poison, *unconscious*;

The only thing I found linking *nonlethal* and *unconscious* is Knocked Out and Dying:

> You gain the dying 1 condition. [...] If the damage was dealt by a *nonlethal* attack or nonlethal effect, you don’t gain the dying condition; you are instead *unconscious* with 0 Hit Points.

It only talks about the **last** damage instance. So it seems that you can fight a Plague Zombie<sup>1</sup> with your fists with full efficiency, dealing 49 *nonlethal* damage, and **then** change to *lethal* damage, taking -2 on the attack.
Is this correct?

---

1. Plague Zombies have 50 HP

Comment: I realize that the title is a bit misleading, but a descriptive one would have been 3 sentences long. You are welcome to modify it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No (and not quite)

Most undead are not immune to non-lethal damage, so you are correct that you can punch them effectively. They lack "non-lethal damage" in their Immunities section, and there is nothing about it in the overarching Undead Trait. Undead are immune to being Unconscious because there are effects that can cause the Unconscious condition outside of damage (such as [Lethargy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=120) and [False Death](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=551) poisons) and there's nothing to say there won't ever be an effect that they're not otherwise immune to.

However, you do *not* need to switch to dealing lethal damage for the last hit. When an Undead is brought to 0 HP by any means, including non-lethal damage, they are [destroyed](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=160). They never interact with the Dying Condition or rules, but instead simply stop functioning, possibly going limp, disintegrating, or dissipating (depending on undead type and GM narration).

Comment: Not sure if it's worth noting in the answer, but there *are* creatures immune to non-lethal damage. So the absence in Undead statblocks (including incorporeal ones) is intentional.