# What creatures are immune to nonlethal damage?

Tags: monsters, pathfinder-2e, nonlethal

Inspired by [this comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/200709/are-undead-immune-to-nonlethal-damage#comment547572_200712) (and the question to which it’s found under), what creatures in PF2e *are* immune to non lethal damage? Is there a complete list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Constructs

> A [construct](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=35) is an artificial creature empowered
> by a force other than necromancy. Constructs are often
> mindless; **they are immune to bleed damage, death effects,
> disease, healing, necromancy, nonlethal attacks**, poison,
> and the doomed, drained, fatigued, paralyzed, sickened, and
> unconscious conditions; and they may have Hardness based
> on the materials used to construct their bodies. Constructs
> are not living creatures, nor are they undead. When reduced
> to 0 Hit Points, a construct creature is destroyed.

Other than constructs, there are four additional monsters currently listed on AoN that are immune to Nonlethal Damage:

- [Ostovite](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=1255) a common level 1 Fiend
- [Eremite](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=852) a common level 20 Fiend
- [Roiling Incant](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=1277)
- And lastly,
  [Guillotine Golem](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=1650), which probably ought to be tagged as a Construct; that appears to be a misprint.